# grails elfinder plugin: use placeholder in rootDir

Tags: grails, elfinder

in my Grails project I'm using elfinder plugin to manage files and directories. I want to have a dynamic root directory, because I use the plugin for different folders.
The path of directory is like the following:

```
grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir = "${userHome}/docm_patients_doc/{patientcf}/"
```

where `patientcf` is the id of an entity in my application. When I enter into the show.gsp page of that entity, I need to replace the patientcf with the related value.
How can I do it?

EDIT:
I've tried to modify the placeholder before the script and div that shows elfinder in gsp page, but I notice that the path is not modified. Maybe the gsp is not the place in which the placeholder can be modified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am author of elfinder plugin, though plugins isn't developed with multiple roots in mind.

You can try this. Plugin registers a spring bean with name elfinderFileManager which has a property with name ‘root’ which is path to your root directory. Try setting the root property at runtime. The bean can be injected in your controller/service and you can try changing the root property.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe I need some further help because I don't know how to perform what are you suggesting to me. May I need to open an Issue in github project of elfinder?

Comment: @FrancescoDS - declare dependency on elfinderFileManager in your controller or service, and change the root property of the bean as you want.

eg
elfinderFileManager.root = "/foo/bar/patientcf/"

Comment: I don't know how to declare dependency in controller...:(

Comment: @FrancescoDS inside your controller class inject a pointer to the service by using def elfinderFileManager

Comment: @JoshuaMoore is it the same done with springSecurityService? If yes, with elfinderFileManager I see the following tooltip: cannot infer type

Comment: @FrancescoDS Yes just like springSecurityService, as far as the tooltip warning I don't know what to suggest other than your IDE isn't able to resolve the dependency but Grails should be able to when you run your application.

Comment: @SudhirN I have similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768310/grails-elfinder-plugin-not-working

Maybe you can help. Also Github issue opened if you prefer: https://github.com/snimavat/grails-elfinder-connector/issues/4