# how to define grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir in external config file

Tags: grails, configuration, elfinder

I want to define the `grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir` path in an external config file.
I've using the following in Config.groovy

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
"classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
"file:${userHome}/docm/${appName}-config.properties",
"file:${userHome}/docm/${appName}-config.groovy"]
```

And I've created the file appName-config.properties, in which I have the following:

```
grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir = "/home/francesco/docm_patients_doc/{patientcf}/"
```

I have two different issues in development and production environments:

- development: when view with elFinder is loaded I've the following exception

  ```
  ERROR elfinder.ElfinderConnectorController  - 
  Error encountered while executing command elfinderOpenCommand
  Message: /home/francesco/IdeaProjects/medicalOfficeManager/"/home/francesco/docm_patients_doc/sderet45t34e345t/"
  Line | Method
  ->>   62 | getTree   in
  grails.plugin.elfinder.filemanager.ElfinderLocalFileSystemFileManager
  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
  |     57 | getTree   in     ''
  |     44 | files . . in grails.plugin.elfinder.command.ElfinderBaseCommand
  |     32 | execute   in grails.plugin.elfinder.command.ElfinderOpenCommand
  |    195 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
  |     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
  |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
  |    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
  ^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
  ```
- production. at application startup, I've the following exception

  grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir is not configured

Why do I have this two different issues?

EDIT:
following the examples given [here](http://blog.zmok.net/articles/2009/04/22/playing-with-grails-application-configuration) and [here](http://phatness.com/2010/03/how-to-externalize-your-grails-configuration/) now I have in both cases the exception that I see in production, that is:

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application:     
grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir is not configured
Message: grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir is not configured
Line | Method
->>   33 | doCall                    in ElfinderConnectorGrailsPlugin$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    757 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|     584 | beans . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    527 | invokeMethod              in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

EDIT 2:

the following is the way in which I replace the placeholder

```
def replacePatientCfInConfig(String patientcf)
{

    def path = grailsApplication.config.grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir?.replace("{patientcf}", patientcf)
    elfinderFileManager.root = path
    return
}
```

this method is called into the gsp page in which I define `<div id="elfinder"></div>`, right before it and also before the javascript needed for elfinder

I've also modified, in development, the way to access the config file as follows:

```
def ENV_NAME = "PROPERTIES_PATH"
    if(!grails.config.location || !(grails.config.location instanceof List)) {
        grails.config.location = []
    }
    if(System.getenv(ENV_NAME)) {
        println "Including configuration file specified in environment: " + System.getenv(ENV_NAME);
        grails.config.location << "file:" + System.getenv(ENV_NAME)
        println(grails.config.location)

    } else if(System.getProperty(ENV_NAME)) {
        println "Including configuration file specified on command line: " + System.getProperty(ENV_NAME);
        grails.config.location << "file:" + System.getProperty(ENV_NAME)
        println(grails.config.location)

    } else {
        println "No external configuration file defined."
    }
```

Now the config file is correctly loaded, but I've the following exception:

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application:
grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir is not configured

Message: grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir is not configured
Line | Method
->>   33 | doCall                    in ElfinderConnectorGrailsPlugin$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    757 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|    584 | beans . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    527 | invokeMethod              in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Where's the path /home/francesco/IdeaProjects/medicalOfficeManager/ is coming from, have you configured it anywhere ?

Are you getting any exception in backend ? can you paste the fullstacktrace here

Comment: that path is the directory of the grails application in which I'm using elFinder. The stacktrace is now in my post above

Comment: I dont know where that path is being appended.. it should not be there. Also note, dynamic part you have there ${patientcf} isnt supported, as far as i remember, you are setting the root property dynamically at run time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547566/grails-elfinder-plugin-use-placeholder-in-rootdir - May be that is setting the incorrect root directory

Comment: the production error is because it is not finding the config, your config file isn't being loaded properly. I hope you have put the config file at right location. Try to do run-war and see if you get the same config error as prod.

Comment: sudhir I replace the path as you can see in my last edit, but I perform that code when I define rootDir in config.groovy. I don't know if it works if rootDir is defined externally. Regarding the path of config file, as you can see in my edit too, now I'm using an environment variable to point at the right path, but I've the same exception as production, that is rootDir is not configured

Comment: sudhir, in my ElFinderConnectorGrailsPlugin.groovy file I have the following: def pluginConfig = application.config.grails.plugin.elfinder

  if(!pluginConfig?.rootDir) {
   throw new RuntimeException("grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir is not configured")
  } maybe it is needed to change something here to let plugin get config rightly?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for development environment.
I've only changed `grails.config.location` in `grails.config.locations`, and changed the syntax of the config file from `grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir = ...` to

`grails{

      plugin{

      elfinder{

      rootDir = ...}

       }

       }`

In production environment, the environment variable is never read...why?